# Add members from Active Directory to my SharePoint Site - WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint

I have a running WSS 3.0 site, I want to give some users permissions to participate in this site ... but I want to add users from my Active Directory user - user@company.com. When I checked "Authentication Providers" I found only one provider Zone:**Default** - Membership Provider Name:**Windows** ... I don't know if this can help.

My boss asked my not to add all the people to the SharePopint machine itself in order to make them able to participate ... could you help me in this :D

Answer (score 1):

If you are setup with the Windows authentication method, that hooks up your authentication to the AD domain that your WSS server is in.

Typically you will want to use Integrated/NTLM authentication so that people on computers in your domain will be automatically logged in with their machine credentials. (People not in your domain or not using IE will need to type in their username/password)

Your users should not need any specific privileges on the Sharepoint server - but you may need to add Domain Users (or nt authority\all authenticated users) to the Users group on your SharePoint machine.

Here is Microsoft's planning guide for WSS authentication:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288475.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When I've done this, it has been a simple matter of going into the Advanced Permissions of the site, selecting the New dropdown, choosing Add User and typing the users' name in the format of DOMAIN\username in the box and choosing the permissions to give them.

Answer (score 0):

I did all of this, but when I try to add any person by the DMAIN\User_name it did not work and sharepoint told me that this name is not correct !

The solution is to add all users to the readers group and when I need to add any specific person for owners or contributors I must make this person log in at least once at the site and then I will find him in the search !!! I tried this three times with three persons !

thank you

Comment: (It would be wiser to add this as a comment to one of the previous answers, not as new "answer" to your question.)